Android Emulator not launching outside Android Studio
I'm trying to launch the Android emulator from Visual Studio Code using Flutter, but it doesn't open properly. The emulator icon appears in the taskbar in gray color, but when I try to open it, I get errors like "lib-android... file not found". I've just installed Android Studio, and I'm not sure why this isn't working correctly.
I tried re installing android studio and flutter itself
